# Grafana: Multilines for java error traces using logback

Tags: cassandra, grafana, logback, grafana-loki

**Versions:**
**Cassandra** v4.1.2 (Helm by Bitnami 10.4.2)
**Grafana-Agent** v0.34.0 (Helm by Grafana 0.15.0)
**Grafana** v9.5.3 (Helm by Grafana 6.57.2)
**Loki-distributed** v2.8.2 5-(Helm by Grafana 0.69.16)

---

I have a Cassandra instance deployed in a Kubernetes cluster. There is also a Grafana Agent deployed there in order to retrieve metrics (sent to mimir) and logs (sent to Loki). I use grafana for visualisation.

The issue is that in Grafana when I want to retrieve the Cassandra logs, the error traces are split line by line

[Too many lines detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXzGq.png)

Cassandra is using logback
I want to have one log entry containing the error and the trace but I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried to tune a bit Grafana Agent with

```
discovery.kubernetes "pods" {
  role = "pod"
}

loki.source.kubernetes "pods" {
  targets    = discovery.kubernetes.pods.targets
  forward_to = [loki.process.test.receiver]
}
loki.process "test" {
  forward_to = [loki.write.default.receiver]

  stage.multiline {
    firstline = "^.*\\[.*\\]"
    max_wait_time = "10s"
  }
}
```

It works for those traces but may break other log format, and I'm not sure that it's the proper way to do it, seems a bit hacky.
Plus the output is also horrible since Grafana shows the whole trace even if the line is not collapsed.